# Python Unicode string to Javascript

Tags: javascript, python, json, unicode

I want to get the output with single backslash in my json file which is an input to my javascript/HTML document. it is for visualization purposes using vis.js
I am unable to get rid of Python's way of adding a backslash before a backslash. I have tried escaping backslash and using r'' type strings.

I have a dictionary:

```
f = {'id':0,'group':'main', 'label':'Main', \
'font':{'size': 60}, 'shape': 'icon', 'icon': {'face':'Ionicons',\
'code': r'\uf276', 'size':200, 'color':'#f0a30a'}, \
'color': {'background': 'pink', 'border': 'black'}}

In [91]: print f
'{'group': 'main', 'color': {'border': 'black', 'background': 'pink'}, 'label': 'Main', 'shape': 'icon', 'font': {'size': 60}, 'id': 0, 'icon': {'size': 200, 'color': '#f0a30a', 'code': '\\uf276', 'face': 'Ionicons'}}
```

I am dumping it into a json file using json.dumps

```
In [92]: json.dumps(f)
Out[92]: '{"group": "main", "color": {"border": "black", "background": "pink"}, "label": "Main", "shape": "icon", "font": {"size": 60}, "id": 0, "icon": {"size": 200, "color": "#f0a30a", "code": "\\\\uf276", "face": "Ionicons"}}'

In [93]: print json.dumps(f)
{"group": "main", "color": {"border": "black", "background": "pink"}, "label": "Main", "shape": "icon", "font": {"size": 60}, "id": 0, "icon": {"size": 200, "color": "#f0a30a", "code": "\\uf276", "face": "Ionicons"}}
```

I am saving this string into a file using json.dump(filename, f) and it is outputting this:

```
{
    "group": "main", 
    "color": {
        "border": "black", 
        "background": "pink"
    }, 
    "label": "Main", 
    "shape": "icon", 
    "font": {
        "size": 60
    }, 
    "id": 0, 
    "icon": {
        "size": 200, 
        "color": "#f0a30a", 
        "code": "\\uf276", 
        "face": "Ionicons"
    }
}
```

Comment: Your backslash is in a raw string (`r'foobar'`), which is why it's actually a backslash, not an escape sequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
json.dumps(f, ensure_ascii=False).encode('utf8')
```

will give you

```
{
    "group": "main",
    "color": {
        "border": "black",
        "background": "pink"
    },
    "label": "Main",
    "shape": "icon",
    "font": {
        "size": 60
    },
    "id": 0,
    "icon": {
        "size": 200,
        "color": "#f0a30a",
        "code": "\xef\x89\xb6",
        "face": "Ionicons"
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
Also the code should be `u'\uf276'`

Answer (score 0):

The string containing the backslash is a *raw string*. It doesn't contain the unicode character you want, but instead an actual backslash, followed by "uf276".

Turn it into a normal string:

```
f = {'id':0,'group':'main', 'label':'Main', \
'font':{'size': 60}, 'shape': 'icon', 'icon': {'face':'Ionicons',\
'code': '\uf276', 'size':200, 'color':'#f0a30a'}, \
'color': {'background': 'pink', 'border': 'black'}}
```

Then the json-dumping should work, too:

```
>>> print(json.dumps(f, indent=4))
{
    "shape": "icon",
    "font": {
        "size": 60
    },
    "label": "Main",
    "color": {
        "background": "pink",
        "border": "black"
    },
    "group": "main",
    "id": 0,
    "icon": {
        "face": "Ionicons",
        "color": "#f0a30a",
        "size": 200,
        "code": "\uf276"
    }
}
```

Comment: it is not working even then. I had tried normal strings too. When I save it using json.dumps(), it just adds an extra backslash before that.

Comment: @mousecoder When you're viewing the resulting string of `json.dumps` in your REPL, of course. But when you print it (or dump it to a file), it's fine, see edit.

Comment: i think the problem is that when you print it, it does not print double backslash but if you save it in a json file the strings appear with double backslash. Can you check that please?